# Which term do I have to look for in the php-documentation for information about string offsets by using $string[$number]?

Tags: php, string, version, documentation

I get the notice:

```
php Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1
```

for the codeline

```
if ($a[-1]==='/') { $a= substr($a,0,-1); }
```

Where could I find the description of the $string[$number] syntax in the php-documentation on php.net?

I didn't get this notice on another computer where in August I installed the newest version of php and where on I wrote this code.

(The notice shows up on an old computer running an older php-version. Or I make a mistake with the current input data. Both could be the reason.)

Comment: ***I didn't get this notice on another computer***. Sounds like that computer had errors and notices turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative string indices were only introduced in PHP7.1 (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php),  *"negative numeric indices"*). You can either upgrade your PHP version, or for lower versions, use the workaround:

```
substr($string, -1, 1)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/m44Or)